# Pandas DataFrame to Impala Table SSL Error

Tags: python, pandas, hadoop, hdfs, impala

I am trying to connect to Impala Shell so I can create tables from Pandas DataFrames from Cloudera Datascience Workbench
based on this blog post:

https://netlify--tdhopper.netlify.app/blog/creating-impala-tables-from-pandas-dataframes/

I get SSL error. Can anyone help me to know what is missing?

```
import os 
import ibis
hdfs_host = 'xxxxx.xxxxx.com'
hdfs_port = xxxxx
impala_host = 'xxxxxx.xxxxxx.com'
impala_port = xxxxxxx
hdfs = ibis.impala.hdfs_connect(host=hdfs_host, port=hdfs_port) 
client = ibis.impala.connect(host=impala_host, port=impala_port, hdfs_client=hdfs, auth_mechanism='GSSAPI', use_ssl=True)
```

Error output

```
failed to initialize SSL
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cdsw/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ibis/backends/impala/client.py", line 113, in _get_cursor
    cursor = self.connection_pool.popleft()
IndexError: pop from an empty deque

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/thrift/transport/TSSLSocket.py", line 281, in _do_open
    return self._wrap_socket(plain_sock)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/thrift/transport/TSSLSocket.py", line 181, in _wrap_socket
    self.ssl_context.load_verify_locations(self.ca_certs)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory


....



TTransportException: failed to initialize SSL
```

Comment: Are you sure you need `use_ssl=True`?

Comment: Yes, I also checked it with False not working.

Comment: Meaning you get a non TLS related error?

Comment: Socket(0) bytes error

Comment: Can you please edit the question with the full stacktrace? If it's just a socket error, that could mean you're connected to the wrong address, or the network is denying the connection